# SWT: How to create a Group without border?

Tags: swt

I'm creating a login form with some labels, text inputs, and a button.
I put them in a Group, but I don't want to have the border of the group displayed.
Is there any way to remove/hide it?

Should I be using other Composite than Group?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think you can create a [Group](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Group.html) without a border.  However, you could use the base [Composite](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite.html) class to group your widgets without a border.  [Here's an example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTCompositeClass.htm) of using a Composite.

If your login form consists of its own [Shell](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell.html) (i.e. window), then you could potentially [layout](http://www.developer.com/design/article.php/3340621) your widgets in the Shell without using a Composite within the Shell.

Comment: I don't recommend placing widgets directly in a shell (without an enclosing Composite).  I've had some very strange layout issues with that sort of setup.  Now, those may be bugs that they have since fixed (this dates back to 3.0 and earlier), but I prefer not to take chances.